# How do I open a .tar.gz magazine file to edit with Scribus?

Tags: downloads, archive, scribus

I downloaded a tar.gz file from [Translate Full Circle](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuMagazine/TranslateFullCircle)
for translating this magazine in my native language, but i can't open it on Scribus(the software to edit any text files)
please help me i really wait for your help.
thank you.

Answer (score 2):

A tar.gz is a compressed format, similar to .zip if you are familiar with that. Simply double-click on it, and it should open with archive manager, where you can extract the real files to somewhere else. These extracted files are what you would open with Scribus.